# automatic addition of editors to Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'll try to explain my problem. I'm very bad at scripts and I'm trying to figure out the script.

I need to add mail to the A:A range, and the script will give these mail the editor role. If I remove mail from the range, then it itself will remove the editor role

for some reason what I have is not working,
but I can't understand why... my friend can't help me, I'm confused. I will be incredibly glad if someone helps me and explains what the problem is

```
    function manageEditors() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('почты');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A:A');
  var emails = range.getValues().flat();
  var editors = sheet.getEditors();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    if (emails[i] !== "" && editors.indexOf(emails[i]) === -1) {
      sheet.addEditor(emails[i]);
    }
  }
  
  for (var j = 0; j < editors.length; j++) {
    if (emails.indexOf(editors[j].getEmail()) === -1) {
      sheet.removeEditor(editors[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

this is what the AI ​​gave me

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var range = e.range;
var editedRow = range.getRow();
var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
var editedValue = e.value;

var emailRange = "A2:A100";
var emails = sheet.getRange(emailRange).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
var email = emails[i][0];

if (editedRow == i + 2 && editedColumn == 1) {
if (editedValue != "") {
addEditor(email);
} else {
removeEditor(email);
}
}
}
}

function addEditor(email) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var editors = sheet.getEditors();

if (editors.map(function(editor) { return editor.getEmail(); }).indexOf(email) == -1) {
spreadsheet.addEditor(email);
}
}

function removeEditor(email) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var editors = spreadsheet.getEditors();

if (editors.map(function(editor) { return editor.getEmail(); }).indexOf(email) != -1) {
spreadsheet.removeEditor(email);
}
}
```

Comment: There is no Class Sheet Method getEditors() read the documentation

Comment: The Protection Class has  a getEditors() methold and it returns an array of Users

Comment: - [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Comment: `for some reason what I have is not working, but I can't understand why` Please share the results of your trouble shooting... what does the Executions Tab show (include entire error message). You have two loops, does one work and the other fail? According to the documentation, `getEditors`, `addEditor` and `removeEditor` are all `Spreadsheet class` methods.

Comment: If I understood correctly what you are asking 
The script neither adds new editors nor removes them 
Perhaps I should have added onedit so that it would run itself based on changes in the range?

TypeError: sheet.getEditors is not a function
manageEditors @ почты2.gs:6

Comment: I also tried repeating my request in AI, but the code it made doesn't do anything either. I added his code to my question above

Comment: `sheet.getEditors is not a function` We've already said `getEditors` is a Spreadsheet class so it _should_ be something like `var editors = ss.getEditors()` . Ditto `sheet.addEditor(emails[i]);` => `ss.addEditor(emails[i]);` and `sheet.removeEditor(editors[j]);` => `ss.removeEditor(editors[j]);`. You've chosen not to include any data, so the least you can do is read and understand the comments, apply them to your script and see whether they fix the problem, or at least advance the script to a new problem. BTW, no-one wants to read the AI-sourced script.

Comment: IT REALLY WORKS
Thanks a lot!

sorry if my stuff about AI seemed somehow offensive or something like that-

Comment: `sorry if my stuff about AI seemed somehow offensive or something like that` Not at all. FYI: at this point in time, AI is not reliable when it comes to developing scripts. Though this is likely to improve, for the time being it's just a waste of time to try and debug most AI scripts. That was the context of my comment, particularly as we already had _your_ script that included some identifiable, but fixable,  errors.

Comment: oh okay, I get it